# How to query object dynamically in documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, object

I have documents of below structure in db

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cfcd787cbac8d69e6db1a8"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "summary" : {
        "Boundry" : false,
        "Six" : false,
        "Wicket" : false,
    }
}
```

I want to find data according to summary i.e Boundry, Six and Wicket

I am able to get my data by using "dot" operator i.e

```
db.getCollection('colection_name').find({"summary.Boundry": true})
```

but I want it to be dynamic so that I can find data by multiple summary key

Dynamic in the sense for Boundry find data by "summary.Boundry": true, for Six I need to find data by "summary.Six": true I wanna make "summary"+".Six" kind of string so that it can dynamically search Is that possible?

I have tried [ElemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to query but it seems to work in array only

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you're asking -- are you trying to write a query like `{"summary.Boundry": true, "summary.Six": false }`? Or are you trying to come up with an aggregation?

Comment: Just use string interpolation `db.getCollection('colection_name').find({[`summary.${key}`]: true})`

Answer (score 1):

You maybe need to elaborate a bit more on what you mean by "dynamic", however, if you simply want to match on one or more fields at the same time you can just include these:

```
db.getcollection('collection_name')
.find(
  { 'summary.Boundry': true }, 
  { 'summary.Six': true }
)
```

MongoDB by default applies the [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) logical operator to your conditions.
If you want an either-or match you can use [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/).

Comment: In fact, the `$and` operator is not necessary in the first case. It could just be `db.getcollection('collection_name').find({'summary.Boundry': true}, {'summary.Six': true })`.

Comment: @VirgilioGM cool, I'm not a huge MongoDB user, just going with the docs. Much like other languages though, it's cool that there are shorthand / default behaviours :)

Comment: hi @James have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use object and make it dynamic according to your condition like this

```
var search={};
    if (yourcondition) {
    search = {"summary.Boundry":true};
    }else if (next condition) {
    search = {"summary.Six":true};
    }else if (next condition) {
    search = {"summary.Wicket":true};
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question still not well formed but what i got from Your question that you don't to hard code query like

```
db.getCollection('colection_name').find({"summary.Boundry": true})
```

So my suggestion you can create query object dynamically like
Example 1: If you want all boundary then

```
 query({"summary.Boundry": true}, {}, {}, function(err, res)=> { // Your further code});
```

Example 2: If you want all six then

```
query({"summary.Six": true}, {}, {}, function(err, res)=> { // Your further code});
```

And query function implementation is like (I added project and options as well in-case you don't all key of document)

```
function query(condition, projection, options, callback){
    db.getCollection('colection_name').find(condition, projection, options, callback)
}
```

I hope I got your problem.